# How do you get into a gold dungeon in the aether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-aether

In the aether mod, I have found severakl gold dungeons, but I can't figure out how to get in. Does anyone know how to get into a gold dungeon from the aether mod?

Answer (score 1):

From a [quick Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=minecraft%20aether%20gold%20dungeon&oq=minecraft%20aether%20gold%20dungeon&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5552j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=94&ie=UTF-8), I found the wiki for the Aether mod, and the [page for the Gold Dungeon](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mods/The_Aether/Gold_Dungeon):

> "The island has no visible entrances other than a small, hangar-type
> corridor partially hidden to one side."

The page has a lot of other helpful info.

Comment: 1) SE is not a forum. It's a Q&A website. 2) Please don't send users away to google, we are here to create a collection of knowledge.

Comment: 1) My bad. I'll try to use correct terminology in the future.
2) I was under the impression that this site encouraged users to do their own research first before posting. I also still believe that the OP's question would have been more quickly answered using any of the already established sources of information.

Comment: 1)No problem, it's just that the two are different and get confused regularly. 2) Lack of research is just a reason to downvote. There is never a good time to make a downward kicking remark (I made the same error with my slightly rude comment, for which I'm sorry). 3) Welcome to the site!